# How to empty and load a div without it resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four thumbnail divs called .jobs enclosed by a #job-wrap. Upon clicking a .job, #job-wrap needs to fadeOut, empty, load .job info in, and fadeIn. However, once emptying the #jobwrap, the rest of my site shoots up due to the .jobs no longer taking any height real estate. How can I maintain #job-wrap's height after I empty it, and load contents in.

```
$('.job').click(function(){
    var job = $(this).attr("name");
    var jh = $('#job-wrap').height();
    $('#job-wrap').css('height', jh);
    alert(jh);
    $('#job-wrap').fadeOut(700, function(){
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).load("content.html#" + job, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(700);
        });
    });
});
```

Here I've tried to set the current #job-wrap's height to itself before the empty begins. (it doesn't work, although the alert does give the current height which varies due to the sites responsiveness)

```
<div id="job-wrap">
                <a class="link">
                    <div class="job" name="eventuall">
                        <div class="job-img">
                            <img src="images/thumb-eventuall.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="job-blurb">
                            <h3>Eventuall</h3>
                            <p>UX Design, Front End </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="link">
                <div class="job">
                    <div class="job-img">
                        <img src="images/thumb-audivy.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="job-blurb">
                        <h3>Audivy</h3>
                        <p>UX Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML the function acts upon. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `content.html#` should be `content.html #`

Comment: Give `#job-wrap` a `min-height` and `animate` the `opacity` instead of using the `fade` method.

Comment: you could put another `div` that contains `#job-wrap`, set that div to the same size in your css as job-wrap but don't add any other style it so that you can't see it when job-wrap fades out, but will still take up the same amount of space

Comment: What if you move `$('#job-wrap').css('height', jh);` just after `$(this).empty();` ?

Comment: I find that opacity is pretty buggy in most scenarios. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `min-height` to `#job-wrap` and instead of fading in and out, animate the opacity instead. The fade method sets the element `display` to `none` in the callback function.

```
$('.job').click(function(){
    var job = $(this).attr("name");
    var jh = $('#job-wrap').height();
    $('#job-wrap').css('height', jh);

    $('#job-wrap').animate({opacity: 0}, 700, function(){
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).load("content.html#" + job, function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 700);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This solved it for me. However, your solution needs the second opacity to be set back to 1, and you have an extra } right after 700.

Comment: Sorry, typo! Corrected my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`.fadeOut()` fades down and then sets the div to `display: none;` - Maybe you can change the opacity and use `visibility: hidden;` or some other property that keeps the div's place in tact? That seems to be the main problem I find with most jQuery methods that end in `display: none;`  --- on the other hand, if you have set sizes, you could put a wrapper around it and then maybe just have the div inside it do what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `min-height` as well as `outerHeight`, and adding an inner wrapper. The outer wrapper will stay visible, and you set the min-height on the outer wrapper. The inner wrapping div is the element that gets emptied and hidden see http://jsfiddle.net/mf933/1/ or use below code:

```
$('.job').click(function(){
    var job = $(this).attr("name");
    var jh = $('#job-wrap').outerHeight();
    $('#job-wrap').css('min-height', jh);
    alert(jh);
    $('#job-wrap-inner').fadeOut(700, function(){
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).load("content.html#" + job, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(700);
            // uncomment to reset the min-height after loading
            // $('#job-wrap').css('min-height', 'inherit');
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Top Content</h1>
<div id="job-wrap">
    <div id="job-wrap-inner"> <a class="link">
        <div class="job" name="eventuall">
                            <div class="job-img">
                                <img src="images/thumb-eventuall.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="job-blurb">
                                <h3>Eventuall</h3>
                                <p>UX Design, Front End </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
     <a class="link">
                    <div class="job">
                        <div class="job-img">
                            <img src="images/thumb-audivy.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="job-blurb">
                            <h3>Audivy</h3>
                            <p>UX Design</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    </a>

        </div>
</div>
<h1>Bottom Content</h1>
```